# How to add lines to contour plot in python `matplotlib`?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following function to illustrate some contour lines :

```
"""
Illustrate simple contour plotting, contours on an image with
a colorbar for the contours, and labelled contours.

See also contour_image.py.
"""
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

X = np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, 0.005)
Y = np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, 0.005)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (np.ones([np.shape(X)[0],np.shape(X)[1]])-X)**2+100*(Y-(X)**2)**2


# Create a simple contour plot with labels using default colors.  The
# inline argument to clabel will control whether the labels are draw
# over the line segments of the contour, removing the lines beneath
# the label
levels = np.arange(-100.0, 600, 1.0)
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, 
                 Y, 
                 Z,
                 levels=levels,
                )
plt.clabel(CS, 
           np.array(filter(lambda lev: lev <5.0, levels)),
           inline=0.5, 
           fontsize=10,
           fmt='%1.1f'
          )

plt.hold(True)


plt.plot(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005),
        np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005),
        np.ones(len(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005)))*100, '-k')

plt.title('Contour Lines and Constraint of Rosenbrock Optimiztion Problem')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The contour plot looks great if you comment out the lines....:

```
# plt.hold(True)


# plt.plot(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005),
#         np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005),
#         np.ones(len(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005)))*100, '-k')
```

[image]

...but I cannot get the lines to show up overlayed on the plot like I need them.  I just simply need them to be overlayed on top of the contour plot. What is the best way to do this?

I know it is [possible in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458192/r-add-a-line-to-contour-plot), but how to do this in `Python` using `matplotlib`?

Comment: Why are you passing three arrays to `plt.plot`? What is the third array `np.ones(len(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005)))*100` supposed to represent?

Comment: nice edits, @hrbrmstr

Comment: Don't spam tags

Comment: The `np.ones(len(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005)))*100` is just supposed to be the z values for the line I'm trying to plot.  As you can see, I really don't care what the z value is - I just need it to be higher than the contour lines in order for it to show up on top of them rather than underneatht

Answer (score 4):

`plt.plot` draws a two-dimensional line from a sequence of x- and y-coordinates. There's no z-coordinate associated with each point, so there's no need to pass in a third array argument. At the moment `plt.plot` is interpreting those arrays as coordinates for two separate lines, and is doing the equivalent of:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005), np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005))
plt.plot(np.ones(len(np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.005)))*100, '-k')
```

Since the second line contains x and y coordinates of up to 100, the axes will be automatically rescaled so that the contour plot is no longer legible.

I think you might be thinking of the `zorder=` argument (which should just be a scalar rather than an array). It's not necessary in this case - since you're plotting the line after the contours it should have a higher `zorder` than the contour lines by default. You can just get rid of the third array argument to `plt.plot`

Also, since you're drawing a straight line with only two points, you only need to pass the start and end coordinates:

```
plt.plot([-1, 1], [-1, 1], '-k')
```

[image]

Comment: okay, thanks @ali_m.  If it's a straight line, I understand how this works.  What if it's a function?  e.g. the unit circle?

Comment: @guimption "Function" is a very broad category! If there's a one-to-one correspondence between *x* and *y* values (e.g. *y = f(x)*) then you could simply construct a range of x coordinates (e.g. using `np.linspace`), then evaluate *f(x)* for those *x*-values. If it's not one-to-one then you could construct a parametric curve (e.g. a unit circle can be expressed as *x = cos(t); y = sin(t)*, so evaluate *x* and *y* for some sequence of *t*s). For the special case of circles you could just use `plt.Circle`.